# Can't concatenate a string inside a batch loop

Tags: batch, batch-file, cmd.exe, string, concatenation

I've been struggling with this for a while now, and I can't seem to figure out why.

I have this batch file:

```
@echo on    
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /F %%x in (FileList.txt) do (
    for /L %%i in (1,1,16) do (
        if %%i LSS 10 (set ctr=0%%i) else (set ctr=%%i)
        echo !ctr!
        set target = \\Server-!ctr! password /user:domain\username
        echo %target%
        echo net use z: %target%
        echo copy %%x "z:%%~pnx" /Y
        echo net use z: /delete
    )
)
```

My ctr variable is being set appropriately, however, when I try to concatenate it, all I get is: \Server-!ctr! password /user:domain\username.  I have tried %!ctr!%, %ctr%, %%ctr, %%ctr%%, all to just have it return the literal characters - not the value.  Interestly enough, when I take out the set command, my echo !ctr! does return the value.  I have also tried enclosing the set parameters in quotes as well - with the same results, just quotes around it.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### What am I missing

You are not using the `set` command correctly.

```
set target = \\Server-!ctr! password /user:domain\username
```

This creates a variable called "target " (note the extra space after the name).

In addition the right hand side of the expression contains spaces, so you also need some quotes.

> Any extra spaces around either the variable name or the string, will not be ignored, SET is not forgiving of extra spaces like many other scripting languages.

Source [set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html)

Try the following replacement:

```
set target="\\Server-!ctr! password /user:domain\username"
```

You are also not using (understanding) delayed expansion correctly.

```
echo %target%
echo net use z: %target%
```

> Delayed Expansion will cause variables to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time.

Source [enabledelayedexpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

This should be:

```
echo !target!
echo net use z: !target!
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [enabledelayedexpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) - Delayed Expansion will cause variables to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time.
- [set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) - Display, set, or remove CMD environment variables. Changes made with SET will remain only for the duration of the current CMD session.